# Buscar todos registros que existem em outra tabela ao menos uma vez

Tags: mysql

Olá, estou com dificuldades para fazer a seguinte query:

Tenho 3 tabelas: **usuarios_categorias**, **orcamentos_principal** e **orcamentos_novo**

Quando um usuário cria um orçamento, o sistema cria um registro em **orcamentos_principal** com as informações principais, sendo elas: Quem criou o orçamento, data de finalização, status e etc.

Na tabela **orcamentos_novo** fica a especificação de cada item, sendo: nome do item (ex: tintas), quantidade, detalhes e a categoria dele (tintas => pintura, por exemplo) e o ID do registro em **orcamentos_principal**

A dúvida é: na tabela **usuarios_categorias** fica salvo as categorias do fornecedor, e isso pode ser vários tipos, como tintas, vidros, elevador e etc

Então o que eu preciso, é que quando um comprador enviar o orçamento (que podem conter varias categorias) todos fornecedores (**usuarios_categorias**) que tiverem ao menos UMA categoria do orçamento, seja retornado na QUERY

Então tenho o seguinte:

```
usuarios_categorias
ID_user | ID_categoria
1         1 (tintas)
1         2 (vidros)
1         3 (elevador)


orcamentos_novo
Titulo  | ID_categoria
Vidros    2
Calhas    5
Piscina   8
```

Repare que na **usuarios_categorias** o usuário tem a categoria Vidros, mas não tem as outras, porém é pra retornar todos os registros (Vidros, calhas, piscinas) porque ele tem pelo menos uma categoria

Não estou conseguindo bolar uma QUERY para isso, o que tenho atualmente:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as QTD_orc FROM orcamentos_principal
JOIN orcamentos_novo
ON orcamentos_novo.id_orcamento = orcamentos_principal.id
WHERE orcamentos_principal.status = 'ativo'
```

Ele busca todos registros, mas não verifica se o usuário tem ao menos uma categoria

OBS: EU sou o fornecedor, quando eu entrar na página de orçamentos disponíveis ele vai ter que buscar todos os orçamentos que EU tenho ao menos UMA categoria, entende? então eu preciso retornar todos os registros de **orcamentos_principal** em que eu tenha pelo menos uma das categorias do **orcamentos_novo** associado a ele

Comment: Pode ser a solução com PHP, implodir a array e reconsultar com IN  pra verificar os usuários com categoria? se der pra resolver assim faço uma resposta.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR Mas nesse caso, ele buscaria TODOS os orçamentos e um por um faria outra consulta ? pensando que pode existir dezenas de milhares de orçamentos, isso me traria problemas no futuro, ou não?

Comment: Por isso da implosão, e de usar o IN, será feito uma consulta apenas.

Comment: Então faça uma resposta por favor, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazendo diretamente na `query` ficaria assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM orcamentos_principais op
 WHERE op.status = 'ativo'
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM orcamentos_novo on
                     INNER JOIN usuarios_categorias uc ON uc.id_categoria = on.id_categoria
               WHERE on.id_orcamento = op.id_orcamento
                 AND uc.id_user = 1) -- Aqui você substitui pelo seu ID
```

Comment: Como eu respondi pro comentário abaixo, não expliquei direito, EU sou o fornecedor, quando eu entrar na página de orçamentos disponíveis ele vai ter que buscar todos os orçamentos que EU tenho ao menos UMA categoria, entende? então eu preciso retornar todos os registros de **orcamentos_principal** em que eu tenha pelo menos uma das categorias do **orcamentos_novo** associado a ele

Comment: @EvertonNeri verifique a alteração que realizei agora

Comment: Eu adaptei ao que eu precisava e funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda! (passei as categorias do usuário na query ao invés do id dele)

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você fez a consulta e pediu os produtos:

```
produto - categoria
arroz   - comida
feifão  - comida
```

E isso está em uma array:

```
$arr = [
   1 => [
       'produto' => 'arroz',
       'categoria' => 'comida'
   ],
   2 => [
       'produto' => 'feijao',
       'categoria' => 'comida'
   ]
];
```

Imploda a coluna categoria da array em uma string:

```
$categorias_cols = array_column($arr, 'categoria');

$categorias_str = implode('","', $categorias_col);
```

Essa será a resposta:

```
comida","comida
```

Concatene corretamente:

```
$categorias_str_ok = '"'.$categorias_str.'"';
```

Faça a consulta pelos usuários usando a função IN do MySQL:

```
'SELECT * FROM sua_tabela_de_usuarios WHERE campo_da_cagoria IN('.$categorias_str_ok.')';
```

Essa query irá trazer todos os usuários que houverem relação com as categorias da array.

Acredito que seja isso que você precisa, tem como fazer direto na query, mas não saberei dizer como.

Comment: Então, não é bem isso que eu preciso, ele realmente irá funcionar, mas no geral, pra que eu preciso disso: Ele vai contar quantos orçamentos existe, quantos eu participo, quantos finalizou e etc, desta forma ele vai retornar os usuários que possuem uma categoria do orçamento, e não o orçamento em si

Comment: Ele vai retornar os usuários, mas você vai ter um array com o pedido correto ? você percorre essa array, compara 'produto categoria' X 'usuario', se for relacionado, soma, caso contrário não faz nada, sacou ? ou eu que não entendi direito ainda ?

Comment: Aaah eu acho que expliquei errado, EU sou o fornecedor, quando eu entrar na página de orçamentos disponíveis ele vai ter que buscar todos os orçamentos que EU tenho ao menos UMA categoria, entende? então eu preciso retornar todos os registros de **orcamentos_principal** em que eu tenha pelo menos uma das categorias do **orcamentos_novo** associado a ele

Comment: Ah, saquei, então você faz a mesma coisa, pega VOCÊ, ai implode suas categorias, as categorias do orçamento novo, e consulta com IN dentro de orcamentos